# Detect/measure scroll speed

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I'm trying to think of a way to ***measure the velocity*** of a scroll event, that would produce some sort of a number which will represent the speed (distance from scroll point A to point B relative to the time it took).

---

I would welcome any suggestions in the form of pseudo code...
I was trying to find information on this problem, online but could not find anything. very weird since it's 2014, how could it be that there is nothing on google for this...weird!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you WANT to know this information?

Comment: I am building something super cool, which is so cool that I don't want to say anything until it has been built. for real. checkout my other cool inventions if you wish - http://codepen.io/vsync/public/

Comment: I would try possibly making a setinterval that checks grabs and stores  an array of maybe 10 values, so you'll have ten values for the ten positions the scroll bar was at for each interval. You can then measure the distance in pixels  between each point to get a velocity. If you need more accurate, smoother measures, do more than ten measuring points.

Comment: Have a look at this for a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel

Comment: @FelixKling - wheel event is not interesting. I want `scroll` event. for touch, wheel or any other form of scrolling.

Comment: Mmmh, I was looking on a page which didn't list a scroll event, but another one did: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/scroll. But what exactly is your question? You already seem to know what to do.

Comment: distance is easy, but should I come about to determine the time? I need a way to measure the time it took when the scroll event fired by the time it ended. I know when it starts but not when it ends I guess.

Comment: Setinterval will give you the time. If you have it set for ten measures at 100ms each, you know the distance it traveled in 1 second.

Comment: Not only the distance in one second, but the acceleration

Comment: "an object in motion tends to stay in motion, unless acted upon by another force" Once you know the speed, just maintain it unless you hit the bottom of the page or the user interacts with the screen again. You dont really need an 'end' time, unless you want to decelerate when the user stops touching the screen. I'd maybe set deceleration to start 1 to 2 seconds after they stop touching screen.

Comment: In each call of the event handler, you can get the current time with `Date.now()`. Then you just subtract the previous time value from the current time to get the difference and update the value that holds the previous timestamp for the next iteration. `var now = Date.now(); var delta = now - previous; previous = now;`

Comment: @FelixKling - what is the previous time? I have to match times between scroll start and scroll end ONLY, and there is no such thing in js..

Comment: The scroll event is triggered continuously while the use scrolls. When it is triggered the first time, there obviously is not a previous time, so you just store `previous = Date.now()`. But when the the event is triggered a second time (during the same scroll "action"), you have a previous time value and you can get the delta.

Comment: @GaryHayes - I know when scroll starts, but don't know when it ends. I can guess that if nothing changed after X milliseconds then the scroll event is over, but then..how would that method work..what do I do in between..that's the question.

Comment: @FelixKling - there is a bug in this method, because on the first time, and after that, if you wait too long, the delta will be huge. run this code: http://pastebin.com/QFHnfYK1

Comment: @vsync: That's why you have to do it correctly, i.e. clearing the previous value when the user stops scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/hKXPP/

Comment: Well, it turned out that there is no need to measure the time AT ALL, since I can relay on the scroll event to fire more or less at the same interval, so I just need to calculate the delta of the distance. it works..i'm working on perfecting it now. thanks ya'll.

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I was thinking as well after I saw the results in the demo. It might differ from device to device though. Anyways, glad you found a solution. Good luck!

Comment: @FelixKling Can you explain to me what is going on in your demo? If I scroll the mouse wheel quickly, I get a low number, if I scroll very slowly, the number doesn't change at all, as if it isn't registering a change. What is the number supposed to represent?

Comment: @GaryHayes: I'd assume that if you scroll too slowly, the `setTimeout` kicks in and resets the previous time value. The value is the time difference between two scroll events. There are certainly ways to make this more robust (it's just a demo after all).

Comment: @FelixKling Okay cool... just wanted to be clear what was going on. Thanks. I assume he might be making a physics type scroll bar that "bounces" when it hits the top or bottom of a page, with whatever momentum it has, then reducing momentum on each bounce.

Comment: check out my answer and what I did with this whole thing

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```js
var checkScrollSpeed = (function(settings){
    settings = settings || {};
  
    var lastPos, newPos, timer, delta, 
        delay = settings.delay || 50; // in "ms" (higher means lower fidelity )
  
    function clear() {
      lastPos = null;
      delta = 0;
    }
  
    clear();
    
    return function(){
      newPos = window.scrollY;
      if ( lastPos != null ){ // && newPos < maxScroll 
        delta = newPos -  lastPos;
      }
      lastPos = newPos;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);
      return delta;
    };
})();

// listen to "scroll" event
window.onscroll = function(){
  console.clear()
  console.log( checkScrollSpeed() );
};
```

```css
body{ height:300vh }
```

Demo page:
http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/taAGd/

Simplified demo:
http://jsbin.com/mapafadako/edit?js,console,output

---

For real fun, give a real website these rules, then copy the JS and run it

Comment: I would like to ask why do you need to set time `timer =0` and to set `timer && clearTimeout(timer); timer =setTimeout(clear,30);`

Comment: @Luke -  I had to re-learn the code now because I totally forgot what I did here. I've updated it a bit, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: I haven't use it in my project yet but I see something that may be an issue,  after scroll the delta is 1 or -1 when it should be 0.

Comment: @Alqin - what do you mean "after scroll" ?

Comment: I was using the touch-pad from my laptop, scrolling with two fingers, at the end of the scroll(scrollend if there would be such event) the value of delta is always 1 or -1.

Comment: I have a question on this IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) – What are the `settings` for? This parameter could only be set at the end of the IIFE, right? `})( mySettings })`

Comment: at the end its not going back to 0, and my animation is stack on value of 3 or 4 sometimes even 40.
i mean its going down 30 20 10 5 4
but doesnt get to absulote 0

Comment: @YehudaZvi - so round the result to fit your specific needs

Comment: @vsync but i dont want to round it, i like the way it gradually declined, i just want it in the end to go to absolute 0

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script to give you an idea 
when you start scrolling a timer increase count var.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
body{height:2000px;}
#get{position:fixed;top:0px;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = null;
    var count=0
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if(timer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timer); 
        }
        function increase(){
             count++
             timer = setTimeout(increase,50)
            }
        increase()
     });
    $('#get').click(function(){
        alert(count)
        count=0
        })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="" type="button" id="get" value="getTime">
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to go to a different webpage to see the code from this answer? And what's wrong with having the HTML wrap? If a novice comes to this page, the HTML wrap for the JS could be very helpful. That kind of thing was helpful for me when I was learning web development. The code in the answer does do, uh, something that may be what Devima intended... but the complaints in the comment above seemed absurdly asinine. Let's not turn stackoverflow into a troll hangout please!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I just custom made for your issue.
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/nefew/3/edit)

You can view the speed of scroll in the console log. It gives negative values for scrolling up and positive for scrolling down. The actual placement of the scroll bar is constantly updated in the scroll window for more information to glean. This should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: it's unacceptable to hammer the CPU in this method, and it's also not so precise. while this is a solution, it will never be something I would actually use in real life.

Comment: and how does it gives me the speed of the scroll, I don't get it. it just prints a number which is getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't leave it running in a real application... you'd use clearinterval() once you've gotten your data. You can see the speed in console.log, which is viewable when you press F12. the number it is printing in the div is just the position of the scroll bar. I made it that way so it would fill up the div and activate the scroll bar.

Comment: On my mouse wheel, I can get it to scroll a max 2700 pixels per second, but if I drag the scroll bar on the screen, I can get upwards of 10,000 pixels per second.