# How to calculate scroll velocity?

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

I've got a simple graph people can drag the position by drag and drop with the mouse.
Currently it stops instantly as soon as the person stops touching but I want to achieve a similar effect as when you scroll through your phone. Keep the velocity as soon as the user lets go, decelerate until it stops.

How do I calculate this.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593286/detect-measure-scroll-speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect/measure scroll speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593286/detect-measure-scroll-speed)