# Achieve fluid skew transform on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, css-transitions, transform

I've been trying to recreate the effect done on this website, www.section32.com, on scroll where the elements are skewed in correspondence to scrolling up or down.

How I've attempted to do this is update the transform:skew value as one scrolls to a limit and then when they stop scrolling to transition back.

However, the effect here is so fluid. Looking at their code they are using transform matrixes, but shouldn't everything that can be done in a matrix be able to be done with normal transform values, too?

How can one achieve this effect and make it as fluid as done here?

Here is my code:

```
window.onscroll=function(){
        if(!os) os=window.pageYOffset; //original scrollTop value
        if(window.pageYOffset-os>0 && ns>-3) ns-=0.125;
        else if(window.pageYOffset-os<=0 && ns<3) ns=Math.abs(ns+=1);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            items[i].style.transform="skew("+ns+"deg) translateY("+ns/2+"px) rotate("+ns/-7+"deg)";
        }
        timer=setTimeout(function(){
            //console.log('scrolling done!', window.pageYOffset);
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                items[i].className+=" inPlace";
                items[i].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
                    var n=this.className;
                    n=n.replace(/inPlace/g, "");
                    this.style.transform="skew(0)";
                    this.className=n;
                });
            }
            os=timer=null;
            ns=-1;
        }, 100);
    };
```

Comment: can we have a complete code to see what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Temani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574603/2315280) you might be missing `transition` property for your elements.

Another thing I can add is that (not all your logic is here so you might already did this) you need to calculate the acceleration of scroll. In the page you gave if you scroll fast the elements skew more and if you scroll slowly you don't even notice that they are skewed. So the scroll event's frequency of fire has to be in the calculation.

Comment: How would you calculate acceleration of scroll? I am not doing it, but how I would do it is final scroll value - original scroll value, but that would style only after scrolling finishes because only then do I know the final scroll value. Right now I am styling on each scroll change and then reverting back once scrolling finishes. I am using a transition already that's how I am listening for transitionend and then fixing it back at skew(0) when it is done.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599173/2315280) is a good answer on how to calculate speed of scroll with a similar example of what you are trying to do. I think you should check it out.

Comment: I am working on isolating just this effect, I'll post the entire code within half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Seen as all elements do the same,..

Instead of looping all the elements and changing the transform.

Change the actual CSS instead.

Here is an example of 1000 div's.

```js
const stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
let a = 0;

for (let l = 0; l < 1000; l ++) {
  const d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerText = l;
  document.body.append(d);
}

setInterval(() => {
  stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.transform=
    `skew(${Math.sin(a)*20}deg)`;
  a = a + 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<style id="s1" type="text/css">
div {
 transform: skew(10deg);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 transition: 1s;
 color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: did you check the link in the question ... the animation depend on the scroll effect, and each element will be transformed depeding on it's postion, so he need to make the loop

Comment: @TemaniAfif  He knows how to do the scroll part, it's `How can one achieve this effect and make it as fluid as done here?`  It's this part I'm answering.